# beamer \againframe showing full frame without any/ with all overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

Let's say I have a frame with three `onslide`/`item`, where the first will originally disappear when the third one shows up. For whatever reason I want to display all three of them again a few slides later, possibly in the appendix with `againframe`. Is there a switch for that? So far I can create the desired output with the following MWE, but I was wandering, whether this could be done easier.

Setting every overlay step active for the last slide (fourth in this case) and disabling that one originally seems a bit inconvenient.

```latex
\begin{frame}<1-3>[label=test]{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-2,4> foo1
    \item<2-4> foo2
    \item<3-4> foo3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% further frames

\againframe<4>{test}
```

[UPDATE] (for clarification)

When I say easier, I think something like the following, maybe using a yet fictional switch `[full]` to display the complete frame on one slide without any overlays. Also notice the fewer characters after the `item` declarations and `\begin{frame}`.

```latex
\begin{frame}[label=test]{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-2> foo1
    \item<2-> foo2
    \item<3-> foo3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% further frames

\againframe[full]{test}
```

Comment: It is not clear for me what is precisely meant by "easier"!

Comment: I updated my question, thanks for your remark.

Comment: I see! Good question!

Answer (score 1):

No guarantees that this won't have any unexpected side effects, but you could switch to handout mode to get the fully uncovered frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=test]{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-2> foo1
    \item<2-> foo2
    \item<3-> foo3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{handout}
\makeatother
\againframe{test}
\makeatletter
\gdef\beamer@currentmode{beamer}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
normal \pause frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution does the job but it prevents to use the handout mode globally. Some additional test is required to switch to handout mode only when necessary, and switch back accordingly.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS You could store the current mode before switching and then restore to this instead of `beamer`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How could I store the current mode?

Comment: @mimuller Maybe you don't actually need to store it: https://pastebin.com/2aKEdsyc